# Shiny: I have already a date input, however I want the possibility to choose to only show data between specific hours of the day i.e. "16:00 - 24:00"

Tags: r, shiny

output$highlight_end_ui <- renderUI({
timeInput("end_high",
"Highlight end",
seconds = F)

I could just make a text input, but I like the interface provided by dateRangeInput.

I have tried to use the timeInput function, but it only highlights the time range.

Comment: create reactive variable that uses the data from dateInput and timeInput input-variables for filtering data.. beware of timezone-issues!!

Comment: SO does not really work like that.. If you want code, hire someone that does the coding for you. On SO, you'll probably get answers when you provide your own minimal, reproducible data, and the code you got stuck on.

Comment: take a look here https://burgerga.shinyapps.io/shinyTimeExample/  for inspiration

Comment: Thanks - will remember.

Comment: I've tried to use the example from the link, but is met with an error: "Error in as.POSIXlt.default: do not know how to convert 'x' to class “POSIXlt”

Could it be because the package is not loaded correctly?

I changed RenderText to RenderUI - can I do that?

Comment: I have been looking at it now, and come up with this example: 

 sliderInput("timeRange", label = "Time range",
                           min = as.POSIXct("00:00",format = "%H:%M"),
                           max = as.POSIXct("24:00",format = "%H:%M"),
                           value = c(as.POSIXct("00:00",format = "%H:%M"),
                                     as.POSIXct("24:00",format = "%H:%M"))),
               actionButton("update", "Update range")
        )
    )))

But i cannot get rid of the date format - it still shows me the current day. I want it to show only time.

Comment: @Wimpel
Regarding your first comment: should I use the DaterangeInput as the reactive variable?

Comment: @Martinen as Wimpel said, you should provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), it will be much easier to help you with that